# Add pagination - syntax error when copy/pasting

Tags: pagination

I want to add pagination to this page: https://documentarynow.org/genre/documentary/
Can anyone explain why neither of these codes works?

The theme developer added this code, which made the page endlessly buffer.

```
                    if ( $total_page > 1 ) {
                        ht_movie_pagination($total_page);
                    }
```

In other pages, the theme developer used this code (which works on other pages), which results in syntax error of unexpected /

```
<!-- Pagination -->
<div class="row">
    <?php
    if ( $movie->max_num_pages > 1 ) :
    ?>
    <nav class="movie-pagination">
        <div class="pagination-left">
            <span><?php echo esc_html__( 'Movie per page: ', 'blockter' ); ?></span>
            <span><?php echo esc_html__( '8 movies', 'blockter' ); ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="pagination-right">
            <div class="page-text">
                <span><?php echo esc_html__( 'Page', 'blockter' ); ?></span>
                <span><?php echo esc_html( $paged ); ?></span>
                <span><?php echo esc_html__( 'of', 'blockter' ); ?></span>
                <span><?php echo esc_html( $movie->max_num_pages ); ?></span>
                <span><?php echo esc_html__( ':', 'blockter' ); ?></span>
            </div>
            <?php
                echo paginate_links(
                    array(
                        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ),
                        'format'       => '',
                        'current'      => $paged,
                        'total'        => $movie->max_num_pages,
                        'prev_text'    => ' ',
                        'next_text'    => ' ',
                        'type'         => 'list',
                    )
                );
            ?>
```

Comment: Do you define `$total_page` or `$movie` variables anywhere, or you paste only this part of code?

Comment: They appear to be defined. I didn't provide the full codes, I only provided the code that I personally added (that resulted in syntax error unexpected / ) and the shorter code that the theme developer added (which resulted in endless animation loader and no page loaded after 30+ seconds).

Comment: );
 $total_page = $movie->max_num_pages;
?>